# Best way to Convert Int[] array to string and string to int[] in .net Compact framework 2.0 through VS2005

Tags: c#, arrays, string, compact-framework, compact-framework2.0

I have an integer array that looks like

```
int[] arr= new int[] {1,2,3,4};
```

and i want to convert this into a string like

```
string str="1,2,3,4";
```

and vice verse in .net Compact framework 2.0.

I have tried using string.join and Array.convertAll to conver int array to string. But it is not working in .Net Compact Framework 2.0.

What is the best and fastest way of doing this in .net Compact framework 2.0?

Comment: Please can you give more detail than "it is not working"

Comment: `string str = string.Join(",", arr);`? As reverse, you can split your string with comma, parse splitted values to `int` and add you array.

Comment: @David Means Array.ConvertAll method not there in compact framework 2.0

Comment: @Soner string.join accepts string array not accept integer array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

string[] strArr = new string[4];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    strArr[i] = arr[i].ToString();

string newStr = String.Join(",", strArr);
```